# Ethereum gas lower limit

Tags: ether, gas

If I send a transaction with too little gas and the transaction is rejected by the network, do I loose the gas already consumed running up to it being run out, or does it get transferred back to my sending address?

Answer (score 2):

If the *gas limit* is set too low, you'll get an "out of gas" error, and all your gas will be burned up (lost).

If the *gas price* is set too low, the transaction will float in the memory pool, and not get confirmed by any miner. You technically won't lose your currency because it's not confirmed, but depending on your wallet software, it may consider it spent. If you create a new transaction that moves all the funds out of the wallet that sent the first transaction, and include enough *gas price* to get it confirmed, it could get confirmed before your stuck one, which would make the stuck one invalid (can't spend funds that aren't there anymore), and would clear out of the memory pool.

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction runs out of gas during execution, we lose the gas we sent in. It's been spent and the transaction is rejected.